# kitty terminal for latex workflow

Tags: pdf, terminal, latex, kitty

when working with latex files, I currently edit them on a vim editor on a kitty terminal and see the pdf output on a zathura viewer.  It works well but it would be better if I could split the kitty terminal and display a latex file and its pdf side-by-side.  Is there a way to do that on a kitty terminal?  (or on a similar terminal...).  In particular, is there a way to display the zathura window on a kitty terminal? (ssh? I have no clue here.)

Answer (score 0):

You can view PDF files in kitty with https://github.com/dsanson/termpdf.py

As for how to view them side by side, use the kitty remote control feature, an example of doing so for images, is here: https://www.reddit.com/r/KittyTerminal/comments/11hmo86/comment/jayxfoe/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3